# O conteúdo da variável não é exibido na View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Ao invés de exibir o valor de `item.Endereco` no WebGrid o que é exibido é um texto ***@item.Endereco.Length > 0 ? item.Endereco.Substring(0, item.Endereco.Length - 3) : item.Endereco***. 
No meu cenário atual tenho que fazer essa validação com o `substring` na View (no webgrid)

```
@grid.GetHtml(
    tableStyle: "grid",
    headerStyle: "head",
    columns: grid.Columns(
        grid.Column("Empresa", "Empresa"),
        grid.Column("Nome", format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = item.Id})">@item.Nome</a></text>),
        grid.Column("Endereco", format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Contato", new { id = item.Id})">@item.Endereco.Length > 0 ? item.Endereco.Substring(0, item.Endereco.Length - 3) : item.Endereco</a></text>)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quando for usar o valor da `variavel` na `view` tem que por o `@` caso contrario será interpretado como **texto**.

`grid.Column("Endereco", format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Contato", new { id = item.Id})">@item.Endereco.Length > 0 ? @item.Endereco.Substring(0, @item.Endereco.Length - 3) : @item.Endereco</a></text>)`

**- Outra solução possivel:**

`@(item.Endereco.Length > 0 ? item.Endereco.Substring(0, item.Endereco.Length - 3) : item.Endereco)`

Utilizar `@(codigo aqui)`

**- No seu exemplo:**

`grid.Column("Endereco", format: @<text><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Contato", new { id = item.Id})">@(item.Endereco.Length > 0 ? item.Endereco.Substring(0, item.Endereco.Length - 3) : item.Endereco)</a></text>`

Comment: Obrigado @MeAudaSilvio funcionou corretamente, porém tenho uma outra situação parecida como esta: a formatação dentro de uma condição if no Html.Row aqui (https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212730/erro-ao-criar-uma-condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-no-html-raw-do-webgrid) eu agradeço.