# Erro ao criar uma condição no Html.Raw do WebGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid, html-helpers

Estou tentando colocar uma condição em uma linha do WebGrid e ocorre o seguinte erro: `Cannot convert lambda expression to type  'string' because it is not delegate type` 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mesmo me baseando nesse post [O conteúdo da variável não é exibido na View](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/212659/o-conte%C3%BAdo-da-vari%C3%A1vel-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-exibido-na-view/212664#212664) com créditos de [MeAjudaSilvio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/70402/meajudasilvio) não consigo fazer funcionar:

```
grid.Column(Model.DescricaoServico_002, format: (item) =>
{
    if (item.Status == 1)
    {
        return Html.Raw(@<text><div><a href="@Url.Action("ExportarPDFSelecionado", "ProcessamentoRegistros", new { idprocessamentodiario = item.IdProcessamentoDiario, idservico = item.Servico_002.Length > 0 ? item.Servico_002.Substring(item.Servico_002.Length - 3, 3) : item.Servico_002 })" target='_blank'>@(item.Servico_002.Length > 0 ? item.Servico_002.Substring(0, item.Servico_002.Length - 3) : item.Servico_002)</a></div></text>);
    }
    else
    {
        return Html.Raw("<font color='red'><b>Inativo</b></font>");
    }
}),
```

Comment: Já conseguiu resolver, Adriano?

Comment: Ainda não @Aline

Comment: Tentou colocar todo teu if inline atribuido a uma variavel e substituir o @ por um "?

Comment: Ah, e também, se seu: item.Servico_002 é uma string msm? qual é o valor dele?

Comment: Oi @Aline muito obrigado pelas sugestões eu coloquei sim o `@` e o item é uma `string` sim, mas eu consegui resolver usando o `string.format`. Vou postar a solução.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido colocando a tag dentro de um `String.format`:

```
return Html.Raw(string.Format("<text><div><a href=\"{0}\" target='_blank'>{1}</a></div></text>", @Url.Action("ExportarPDFSelecionado", "ProcessamentoRegistros", new { idprocessamentodiario = item.IdProcessamentoDiario, idregistro = item.IdRegistro, Parametro = item.Parametro, idservico = item.Servico_002.Length > 0 ? item.Servico_002.Substring(item.Servico_002.Length - 3, 3) : item.Servico_002 }), item.Servico_002.Length > 0 ? item.Servico_002.Substring(0, item.Servico_002.Length - 3) : item.Servico_002));
```